# Creating RSS Feed In Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to match this tutorial with the news stories that I have for it to post but somewhere something isn't working and I'm not quite sure where.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/building-an-rss-2-0-feed-with-codeigniter/

I already have the text and xml helpers autoloaded.

Page URL: http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/news-feed

**Model:**

```
<?php

class Newsfeedmodel extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
} 

// get all postings  
function getPosts($limit = NULL)  
{  
    $this->db->select('site_news_articles.article_title, site_news_articles.permalink, site_news_articles.date_published');
    $this->db->from('site_news_articles'); 
    $this->db->where('site_news_articles.is_approved', 'Yes');
    $this->db->where('site_news_articles.status_id', 1);
    $this->db->order_by('site_news_articles.date_published', 'desc');  
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array(); 
}   

}

?>
```

**View:**

```
    <!--?php  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . $encoding . '"?-->' . "\n"; ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">

    <channel>
<link><!--?php echo $feed_url; ?-->
    <description><!--?php echo $page_description; ?--></description>
    <dc:language><!--?php echo $page_language; ?--></dc:language>
    <dc:creator><!--?php echo $creator_email; ?--></dc:creator>

    <dc:rights>Copyright <!--?php echo gmdate("Y", time()); ?--></dc:rights>
    <admin:generatoragent rdf:resource="http://www.codeigniter.com/">

    <!--?php foreach($posts--->result() as $post): ?>

        <item>
 <link><!--?php echo site_url('blog/posting/' . $post--->id) ?>
          <guid><!--?php echo site_url('blog/posting/' . $post--->id) ?></guid>

            <description><!--[CDATA[ <?php echo character_limiter($post--->text, 200); ?> ]]></description>
 <pubdate><!--?php echo $post--->date; ?></pubdate>
        </item>

    <!--?php endforeach; ?-->

    </admin:generatoragent></channel>
</rss>
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Newsfeed extends CI_Controller
{

function Feed()  
{  
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('newsfeedmodel', 'posts');
}  

function index()
{

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/



    $data['feed_name'] = 'Kansas Outlaw Wrestling, LLC.'; // your website  
    $data['encoding'] = 'utf-8'; // the encoding  
    $data['feed_url'] = 'http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/newsfeed'; // the url to your feed  
    $data['page_description'] = 'True Outlaws of the Midwest'; // some description  
    $data['page_language'] = 'en-en'; // the language  
    $data['creator_email'] = 'kowmanagement@kansasoutlawwrestling.com'; // your email  
    $data['posts'] = $this->posts->getPosts(10);  
    $this->output->set_header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml"); // important! 
    $this->load->view('rss', $data);  

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

}
}

/* End of file newsfeed.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/newsfeed.php */
```

**EDIT:**
With the code above I'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/xtremer/public_html/application/views/rss.php on line 1
```

Comment: The error message you linked to states exactly what the error is and where it's located: `syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/xtremer/public_html/application/views/rss.php on line 1`

Comment: huh odd because I'm getting a new window box that asks me to open or save a file

Comment: One problem is that your Feed controller constructor is calling `parent::Controller();` instead of `parent::__construct();` or `parent::CI_Controller();`. Also, CI has a function for setting the output header, instead of using the PHP function: `$this->output->set_header();`

Answer (score 3):

> somewhere something isn't working and I'm not quite sure where.

The error message you linked to states exactly where the error is located:

> syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/xtremer/public_html/application/views/rss.php on line 1

Line 1 of that file is this:

```
<!--?php  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . $encoding . '"?-->' . "\n"; ?>
```

That's not valid syntax. From the tutorial you referenced, what you want is:

```
<?php  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . $encoding . '"?>' . "\n"; ?>
```

It looks like you have multiple instances of PHP tags incorrectly written in your view like `<!--?php` so you'll have to correct those as well.